# Whose job is it to ensure people are not being unIslamic?

Tags: sharia, allah

In countries like Saudi Arabia, Aceh, Malaysia, etc people are fortunate that the government helps those who do not conform to the will of Allah(swt) by acting or dressing in a way contrary to the way he wishes for us to behave.

In countries currently dominated by the Kuffar (non-Muslims), like in England, whose job should it be to make sure our sisters don't fall out of line? Especially those who have bad parents, those who do not take responsibility for their children's actions?

Comment: Either it is state or everyone is responsible for himself. You can't force Islam on someone. Not even on your own daughter.

Comment: Well, you always have the obligation of hijrah. If you have means to do it, scholars say that is better.

Comment: @HasanKhan +1 There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.  http://quran.com/2/256

Comment: @Abdullah we also have the obligation of salah, but can you force it on anyone? Obligation means that not doing it will have negative consequences in front of Allah, but doesn't mean there should be compulsion to do it. Obligation not equal to compulsion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalamualaikum.

It's the job of everyone who have a strong sense of the knowledge of Islamic Shariah and Quran to guide every other Muslim or non-Muslim to the right direction and to inform them about their path(if they are not following the dictates of Islam). Any Muslim **must** encourage others in performing the duties imposed by Allah.

Comment: I agree brother, it is our duty as muslims to ensure others follow allah's will.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Islamic law called "ENJOINING GOOD & FORBIDDING EVIL"
in countries without Islamic government this is not done by government but Muslims should advice each other.

The Holy Qur'an enjoins us again and again to do `amr-bil-ma'roof` and
`nahya 'anil munkir`. In suratul aale-Imran  Allah says:

> You are the best community raised up for mankind. You enjoin right conduct
>   and forbid evil (you do amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil munkir) and you
>   believe in Allah."[3:110]
>   Please also see the ayah [3:104], [9:71] and [31:17].

At the same time Islam safeguards an individual's right to privacy in the
strongest possible terms. In suratul Hujaraat  Allah says:

> "O you who believe! Avoid much suspicion, for indeed suspicion (in some
>   cases) is a sin. And spy not, nor backbite one another. Would one of you
>   like to eat the flesh of his dead brother?" [49:12]

Amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil munkir inevitably involve encroachment
upon some one's right to privacy. Where the exercise by an individual of
his right to privacy is likely to adversely effect the right of another
individual or a group or the ummah or the mankind, that right of privacy
is forfeited and the ummah has the duty to counsel that individual.

A few ahaadeeth on the subject are worth noting:

> The Holy Prophet (SAWAW). has said :The world is like a ship and mankind
>   its passengers. The welfare of all depends upon the safe conduct of each.
>   If anyone is found making a hole on the side of a ship, he must be
>   stopped.

The Holy 5th Imam (AS) "Amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil munkir are the
most important obligations because upon them depend the performance of
all other obligations. If amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil munkir are done
the earth will become a safe place, enemies will be subdued and all other
affairs discharged satisfactorily"

> The Holy Prophet (SAWAW) said "He who does amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya
>   'anilmunkir is the vicegerent on the earth of Allah, His Prophet and His
>   Book."

Addressing the Muslim scholars in Mecca after he had left Madinah on his
way to Kerbala, Imam Hussain (A.S.) remonstrated with them because of
their failure to do amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil munkir. This is a
very long hadith and is reported in Al-Tawhid Vol.VII, No.4 p.41. It also
explains Imams's stand against Yezid. I request the administration to
arrange to post the Hadith.

Now let us revert to your specific concerns. The fuqaha are all agreed on
an individual's duties with regard to amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil
munkir and the difficulties one often confronts. I am assured that
Ayatullah Khameni's views coincide with those of Ayatullah Ruhullah
Khumaini and marhum Ayatullah Khui, upon whom I have mostly relied.

Amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil munkir are wajib-e-Kifaai. If one person
does it, it is saqit on the others. If no one does it all are equally
accountable, regardless of their financial or social status, provided the
following requirements are met:

(a) he himself is aware of what is good and what is bad from the Islamic
    point of view;

(b) he believes that the person to whom he wishes to do amr-bil-ma'roof
    and nahya 'anil munkir will listen and follow the advice. If he is
    satisfied that the person will not under any circumstances listen to the
    advice, it is then not wajib upon him to do amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya
    'anil munkir to that person;

(c) he is satisfied that by his undertaking to do amr-bil-ma'roof and
    nahya 'anil munkir no personal or financial suffering will be caused 
    to a third party.

Ways of doing amr-bil-ma'roof and nahya 'anil munkir:

(a) By tongue. By talking to the person and persuading him, using the
    politest posible language to start off with.

(b) By conduct. If talking produces no result, a gradual withdrawal of
    friendship and companionship should be resorted to.

(c) (in Islamic Government) The next stage should be to report the matter to 'alam-e-shar'a (the
    mujtahid whose muqallid you are or his duly appointed "wakil" authorised
    to decide jurisprudential matters).

**References:**

http://www.islamic-laws.com/AmrBilMaroof.htm

http://www.al-islam.org/organizations/aalimnetwork/msg00304.html

Comment: When you copy something from somewhere you should make it a point to format it properly & not just copy paste.

Comment: Forbid evil doesn't mean physically making other people adhere to Islamic rules right? Perhaps it means guiding people in best way possible?

Comment: @HasanKhan in some cases it is in form of physically making. but it needs permission from Islamic ruler and a Muslim personally is not allowed to do this. it is step by step. in some cases it is in form of battle. like battle of Imam Hussain S.A. against Yazid at Karbala. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Karbala

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stories of the prophets(pbut) in the quran. Most of them were sent to nations that were deep in kufr. So I feel it is pretty whiny if a person complains of not having these governments.

These prophets(pbut) were responsible to give their messages. To enforce is the responsibility of the person themselves. In the end, it is Allah that guides.

**Most Muslims in the west should read a book "Enjoy your Life" by Dr. Muhammad Adb Al-Rahman Al-Arifi, it is based on hadith and life of Prophet Muhammad(pbuh).**

So, when there is an consensus / ijmah about the rules of Islam, then governments come into picture to enforce these values at a later stage.

Today even after all these governments in Saudi/Malaysia etc if a person wants to do evil they can do so by switching on their computer. So the problem is not "enforcement" rather "guidance". If a person is rightly guided and in the worst country of the world, still they will not be swayed by the evil around.

For parents, if you are a good example to children, Insha Allah they will be good muslims IN ANY COUNTRY. If you dont have a beard and try to enforce hijab on your daughter, pls dont expect any wonders. If you have not set a good example by praying five times, dont expect them to do so either. BUT if you have done all you could, the it is Allahs will to guide.

Today most muslim parents look angry & smile less. Its probably because they are in a new land and have troubles of their own. But smiling and listening to what your child did in school goes a long way.

Next, I would say just give dawah /islah to people and automatically things will fall in line.

I would also take exception to how you frame your question "sisters out of line". I am sure there are "brothers way out of line" too.